# INSERT or UPDATE bulk data from dataframe/CSV to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Requirement:** **Insert** new data and **update** existing data in **bulk** (row count > 1000) from a dataframe/CSV (which ever suites) and save it in PostgreSQL database.

**Table: TEST_TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
itemid varchar(100)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(255),
street varchar(10),
pincode VARCHAR(100));

INSERT: ['756252', 'tom title', 'APC Road', '598733' ], 
        ['75623', 'dick title', 'Bush Road', '598787' ], 
        ['756211', 'harry title', 'Obama Street', '598733' ]
```

**dataframe content:**

```
data = [['756252', 'tom new title', 'Unknown Road', 'pin changed' ], 
        ['75623', 'dick new title', 'Bush Road changed', '598787 also changed' ], 
        ['756211', 'harry title', 'Obama Street', '598733'],
        ['7562876', 'new1 data title', 'A Street', '598730'],
        ['7562345', 'new2 data title', 'B Street', '598731'],
        ['7562534', 'new3 data title', 'C Street', '598732'],
        ['7562089', 'new4 data title', 'D Street', '598733']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['itemid', 'title', 'street', 'pincode'])
```

I want to **UPDATE** the records with same **itemid** and **INSERT** the new records. The data will be huge (CSV file created from the dataframe is more than 50MB).

Programming language used: **Python**

Database: **PostgreSQL**

Comment: Create a temporary table, use COPY to move the data, do an INSERT ... ON CONFLICT from the temporary table to the actual table.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to deal with bulk data? It will be very costly operation if it is done each row at a time in a loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case it is better to drop down to DB-API level, because you need some tools that are not exposed even by SQLAlchemy Core directly, such as [`copy_expert()`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). That can be done using [`raw_connection()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection). If your source data is a CSV file, you do not need pandas in this case at all. Start by creating a temporary staging table, copy data to the temp table, and insert to the destination table with conflict handling:

```
conn = engine.raw_connection()

try:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST_STAGING ( LIKE TEST_TABLE )
                       ON COMMIT DROP""")

        with open("your_source.csv") as data:
            cur.copy_expert("""COPY TEST_STAGING ( itemid, title, street, pincode )
                               FROM STDIN WITH CSV""", data)

        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE ( itemid, title, street, pincode )
                       SELECT itemid, title, street, pincode
                       FROM TEST_STAGING
                       ON CONFLICT ( itemid )
                       DO UPDATE SET title = EXCLUDED.title
                                   , street = EXCLUDED.street
                                   , pincode = EXCLUDED.pincode""")

except:
    conn.rollback()
    raise

else:
    conn.commit()

finally:
    conn.close()
```

If on the other hand your source data is the `DataFrame`, you can still use `COPY` by [passing a function as `method=` to `to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method). The function could even hide all the above logic:

```
import csv

from io import StringIO
from psycopg2 import sql

def psql_upsert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection

    buf = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buf)
    writer.writerows(data_iter)
    buf.seek(0)

    if table.schema:
        table_name = sql.SQL("{}.{}").format(
            sql.Identifier(table.schema), sql.Identifier(table.name))
    else:
        table_name = sql.Identifier(table.name)

    tmp_table_name = sql.Identifier(table.name + "_staging")
    columns = sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, keys))

    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        # Create the staging table
        stmt = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {} ( LIKE {} ) ON COMMIT DROP"
        stmt = sql.SQL(stmt).format(tmp_table_name, table_name)
        cur.execute(stmt)

        # Populate the staging table
        stmt = "COPY {} ( {} ) FROM STDIN WITH CSV"
        stmt = sql.SQL(stmt).format(tmp_table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(stmt, buf)

        # Upsert from the staging table to the destination. First find
        # out what the primary key columns are.
        stmt = """
               SELECT kcu.column_name
               FROM information_schema.table_constraints tco
               JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
               ON kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
               AND kcu.constraint_schema = tco.constraint_schema
               WHERE tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
               AND tco.table_name = %s
               """
        args = (table.name,)

        if table.schema:
            stmt += "AND tco.table_schema = %s"
            args += (table.schema,)

        cur.execute(stmt, args)
        pk_columns = {row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()}
        # Separate "data" columns from (primary) key columns
        data_columns = [k for k in keys if k not in pk_columns]
        # Build conflict_target
        pk_columns = sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, pk_columns))

        set_ = sql.SQL(", ").join([
            sql.SQL("{} = EXCLUDED.{}").format(k, k)
            for k in map(sql.Identifier, data_columns)])

        stmt = """
               INSERT INTO {} ( {} )
               SELECT {}
               FROM {}
               ON CONFLICT ( {} )
               DO UPDATE SET {}
               """

        stmt = sql.SQL(stmt).format(
            table_name, columns, columns, tmp_table_name, pk_columns, set_)
        cur.execute(stmt)
```

You would then insert the new `DataFrame` using

```
df.to_sql("test_table", engine,
          method=psql_upsert_copy,
          index=False,
          if_exists="append")
```

Using this method upserting ~1,000,000 rows took about 16s on this machine with a local database.

Comment: What does the ON CONFLICT , DO UPDATE SET, EXCLUDED. do? So that will UPDATE any duplicate id rows on the TEST_TABLE with the values from the TEST_STAGING table? Thanks and good job.

Comment: Explaining them in the space of a comment would be challenging, so I will refer you to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html, but you got the gist of it already.

Comment: For postgresql, `TEST_STAGING` needs to be quoted as `"TEST_STAGING"`

Comment: It does not need quoting, if you consistently use regular identifiers, as is done here in the first part. If you or a library decide to use delimited identifiers (quoted), then yes.